# How do I create new string list with all matchings from a previous list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, multiplication

I am attempting to make a basic blackjack game in python and I would like to create and new list called `Deck`. I would like `Deck` to have all possible suit/rank pairings (i.e. Ace of Heart, 2 of Heart, 3 of heart, etc) in one list so I can start "dealing" in a `random.shuffle` or `.pop` style.

How can I pair both these lists or do I have to type it out myself?

Here is the current code:

```
print ("Welcome to the Blackjack Table! May I have your name?")
user_name = input("Please enter your name:")
print ("Welcome to the table {}. Let's deal!".format(user_name))
import random

suits = ["Heart", "Diamond", "Spade", "Club"]
ranks = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10,}

deck =
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to pair each rank with each suit.

```
deck = [(rank, suit) for rank in ranks for suit in suits]
```

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can be used to accomplish the same thing:

```
import itertools
deck = list(itertools.product(ranks, suits))
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is take each suit and pair it with each rank. The code below does exactly that with two nested [for loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
deck = []  # create an empty list
for suit in suits: 
    for rank in ranks:
        deck.append((suit, rank))  # append a tuple to the list
print len(deck)  # prints 52, as expected
```

A more pythonic way is to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It is a tiny bit faster, but might be less (or more) intuitive.

```
deck = [(suit, rank) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]
```

Comment: I find the list comprehension more intuitive myself. But by the way, your two versions are not exactly identical, in that they'll make lists in different orders, though they will end up containing the same values.

Comment: @Cyphase well spotted, I fixed the list comprehension. I prefer the list comprehension too, but using for might be easier to grok for someone without a mathematical background or coming from another language.